# Is it reasonable to use global variables in an AngularJS application or should I have $scope before almost everything that's shared around?

Tags: angularjs

I find that I am using $scope before all variables and functions that I have which are defined in one place and then used in my application. For example:

```
var app = angular
    .module('app',
      ....
      ...
    .run(['$rootScope', '$angularCacheFactory', 
        function ($rootScope, $angularCacheFactory) {

        $scope.one-hour-cache = $angularCacheFactory('1-hour', {
            maxAge: 3600000, 
            cacheFlushInterval: 3600000, 
            deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive',
            storageMode: 'localStorage'
        });
```

How can I make so I don't always use $scope to reference every variable like this?

Would it be reasonable to have some globals so that my application is not full of $scope..... =

If so then where should I define the variables and how ?

Comment: Do you know that you can create services to hold global data and have it injected into whatever needs to use that data?

Comment: I think that is no a "right" answer to your question, I mean, it'll depend on what do you need. Every project is a different world, so, according what you need you can pick up one or another one solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should encapsulate those data or whatever struct it is into a service and have it injected in your controllers. Having it injected is going to pay off in the future while writing your tests.

Answer (score 2):

To improve the communication in your App you could use events, and If you'd want to dig into more, you could take a look to the observer and mediator patterns.

http://jorshasaur.us/simple-observer-pattern-in-angular/

Anyway, if you'd want to use a "global variable" you must add it to the `$rootScope`